# Secure connection to my Static web page hosted on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https

I am trying to static hosting with S3.
I figured that the bucket should be public to have hosting on it, **Is there a way to have it private**?
I also figured out that the domain name should be same as its bucket name, **IS there any other way**?
Also could see that it has only HTTP traffic to it. How can I make it https how will I be adding SSL certificate to it ?

I know it's a string of questions, but it;s been running on my mind.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It will depend what you mean by private, however I am going to assume you simply want to restrict access to the static page itself. I would suggest adding a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of the S3 bucket, using a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) with configured rules to restrict traffic to the host. In addition configure it with an [origin access identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to ensure all traffic to the S3 bucket is received from your CloudFront distribution only.

S3 domain based routing it reliant on the `Host` header being the same as the S3 bucket, if you did create a CloudFront distribution you could use an S3 origin. This would not support any of the S3 website features, but would render assets such as HTML, JS and images. Some of the features that are in S3 website configuration you can reproduce with a [Lambda@Edge function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/).

CloudFront supports an SSL via ACM, although it must be located in `us-east-1`.